# I am trying to click on "one arrow button" multiple times using ng-click but i am not able to click

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

I have to click on arrow button 3 times using ng-click or class.

Pleas help me

Comment: Are you having difficulties identifying the element?

Comment: No but i am not able to click on the arrow button.

Comment: What is the exception then?

Comment: ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Comment: Hi, can you also post your controller code? Can you specify a little more about the problem when you click?

Comment: I am doing in protractor angular. can i click on arrow button more than once using classs or ng-click in protractor.

Comment: I am new to protractor please help me

Comment: Anyone help me out of this please

Comment: Is that the only element with `[ng-click='move(1)']`?

Comment: yes, that arrow element contains ng-click and class.Please help me @Saifur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have mentioned that's hidden element and Selenium does not interact with hidden element the only option you have is javascript. I would try the following and see if that does the work:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"[ng-click='move(1)']\").click();")
```

Or:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-click*=move]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: I am using Python. How to do in python please help me. @saifur

Comment: @alecxe  It is not working , throwing this error "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find_element_by_css_selector'"

Comment: @raghavendrat how have you defined `driver`?

Comment: @alecxe browser.driver.findElement_by_css_selector

Comment: @raghavendrat `driver` should be a webdriver instance. For example, `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`.